# git pull with new latest tag info on the file

Tags: html, git, tags, commit, pull

been trying to find out if there is a way to pre-write the tag version inside a file, so each time when i pull the code from repo, it should write the latest tag version number automatically. so i would know, which guy is using that file from which version..

> is there a way to put **tag information on a file**, so when i retrive 
>   the file it **pre-write the current tag id on** it?

i have search many places, but cant find proper answer.. some way using git describe and some say use hook..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `man gitattributes`, particularly the filter section.

Comment: i want to inject tag version (tag name) inside a file, before commiting or before pull.. eaither way.. just need tag name injection..

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this?

```
git describe --tags > version.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are misunderstanding some concept on tag.

You can say, a tag is an alias of a particular SHAsum of a commit.

You can also checkout the file to a particular point through its SHAsum

`git checkout <Shamsum of a point> -- <path to file>`

or by tagname

`git checkout <tagname> -- <path to file>`

you can always keep track which one did the correction, or made commit on that particular file.

`git blame -- <path to file>`  (the latest version)

or

`git log -- <path to file>` to see all the commits on that particular file

Hope this help

Comment: i want to inject tag version (tag name) inside a file, before commiting or before pull.. eaither way.. just need tag name injection..